# Escape special character in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, django-templates

i'm generating password with letters, digits and special characters `('¿"&$%/\>]{}(=?)*@!<-_¡+[')` and i need to escape special character in templates like ASCII symbols, i generate a list of values like this

```
['0iw0Vqds)*\xc2Ni1P', '<gFLbKi}55(dN[R', '5G<E\\3}+vz72vu{', 'q3ojs$S33rQW$vs', 'IhAV$@3H3uNx\xbfOI', 'uA>>u\\g\xa1vf0\xc2o4t', 'siNyC$JX46bDXZ\xc2', 'R<8\xa1Y{\\]{Wcd/G>', 'D()SuvqdokB\xc2tcR', 'z31LPP{[$n{6_p\xc2']
```

i my template i do:

```
{% for var in password_list %}
    {{var|escape}} 
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using utf-8 in my views.py (# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-). and i tried with `{{var|escape}}` and `{{var|escape|safe}}` but the templates only show in this case the third element in list (q3ojs$S33rQW$vs)

what can i do??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to be using `¿` and `¡` then you're going to need to be using `unicode`s instead of `str`s.

[Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)